# How to use category slug with a regular page

Tags: categories, permalinks, pages

To make better looking category pages in my sites, I'm looking for a way to show the content of a regular page on the permalink /category/name.

How can I achieve that ?

Thanks

Comment: `/category/term-slug` is usually an archive of posts associated with that term. Are you saying that you'd like to override that archive with your page?

Comment: @bosco that is exactly what I am saying